# Model Identification SEM hybrid models - where to add constraint?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

I am using a four-factor (moral orientations) scale (validated in previous research) to predict an outcome (moral violation perceptions) which is a latent variable, measured by four indicator(see attached for my  model diagram). Each of the four factors is made up of 7 items (indicators). I want to test a model where each of the four factors (Integration, Deliberation, RuleF, Sentiment) is predicting the latent outcome (MViol in my model diagram). I believe this is sometimes referred to as a "hybrid model". I could simply calculate a mean for each of the four factors/subscales and examine how they predict the outcome, but it seems like there could be some advantage to using SEM instead of simple multiple regression.

It has been a while since my SEM course, so I could use some help on what variables I need in my model and what kinds of constraints might be appropriate. I'm currently using AMOS. When I set up this kind of model including a residual (error) variable for my endogenous outcome variable, the model becomes unidentified. What is the correct thing to do here? Do I need this residual error variable in this case? I can fix that error variable to 1 and the model will run, but I'm not sure if that is appropriate. What other constraints should/could I add to make the model identifiable? The model will also run if I connect the the five endogenous variable with covariance arrows instead, but I don't think this is what I want when I'm trying to "predict" my outcome. Any advice would be greatly appreciated[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSRkQ.jpg)

Comment: Are deliberation and ruleF deliberately not correlated? That's the only pair of latents that aren't related.

Comment: Try changing the regressions to covariances. I think that's an equivalent model (or very nearly).

Comment: Jeremy, thank you very much for your answers, yes, deliberation and ruleF are the only ones that are not correlated. If I change the regressions to covariances then the model becomes identified. Do you happen to know what the difference between regressions and covariances is in this case?

Comment: I think that Amos is changing adding a constraint when you have covariances (or removing it when you have regressions). It does this to try to be helpful, but it's often not. Does it list the free parameters in the model when it runs? If so, run both models and compare the lists. (Do the models have the same df?)

Comment: Df is 910 for the regression model and 912 for the covariance model. You lose 2 df for estimating the variance for the error variable for the endogenous outcome and its regression weight. In the model I attached above I fixed the error variance to 1 and when you do this the df become 912, just like for the covariance model which doesn't have this error variable. My question is whether I NEED to be estimating this error variable and what the differences between the regression and covariance approach are (i.e., if I write this up for publication, how can I defend my approach?)

Comment: I think what I am asking is, what is the (statistical) difference between the single-headed and double-headed arrows in my case? Ultimately, everything in this model is correlational, but does the estimation of the paths or covariances differ significantly depending on which type of arrow is used?

Comment: I made a room to discuss this further: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70126/discussion-about-https-stats-stackexchange-com-questions-318256-model-identific

Comment: Thanks for making the room! I can view it but I can't seem to post because I don't have a 20 reputation yet. I am just drawing up a document that shows the different  models, variable counts and diagrams. Is there some convenient way I could share this with you?